Unable to access protected or admin pages with Auth0
I managed to run the backend following the steps described in this link: NestJS Code Sample: API Role-Based Access Control
I managed as well to run the frontend following the steps described in this other link: React Router 6/TypeScript Code Sample: Basic Authentication
However whenever I try to retrieve content from both pages protected or admin I get Unauthorized, even though I am getting a JWT token with getAccessTokenSilently right before sending the request. When I check the API call in the bakend I cannot see any signal from Bearer tokens.
Here goes a piece of the react code that I use to access the protected endpoint:
  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    let token: string
    (async () => {
      token = await getAccessTokenSilently()
      console.log(token)
      const getMessage = async () => {
        const { data, error } = await getAdminResource(token);

        if (!isMounted) {
          return;
        }

        if (data) {
          setMessage(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }

        if (error) {
          setMessage(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        }
      };
      getMessage();

    })()
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);


What am I doing wrong?
Edit
export const getAdminResource = async (token: string): Promise<ApiResponse> => {
  const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3030/api/messages/admin',
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    },
  };


can you share your getAdminResource function?

@unhackit, I edit my question to share that function as well
